# npm link not working on windows?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using node v0.10.32. Windows 8.1.

My objective is to link a node application as a node_module in another main app.

I go to my-module folder and do

```
npm link
```

Then, I go to the main-app folder and do

```
npm link my-module
```

This is the result

```
c:\dev\main-app>npm link my-module
unbuild my-module@0.0.2
c:\dev\main-app\node_modules\my-module ->     C:\Users\Nizar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\my-module -> C:\dev\my-module
```

But, the linkage does NOT seem to work, **require('my-module')** throws the following error

```
    c:\dev\main-app>node app.js

    module.js:340
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'my-module'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
```

- my-module is indeed v0.0.2.
- I can access it from main-app/node_module/my-module
- This folder exists C:\Users\Nizar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\my-module
- my-module package.json has "name": "my-module"

Moreover, %NODE_PATH% is correctly set:

```
  c:\dev\main-app>echo %NODE_PATH%
  C:\Users\Nizar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

Ideas?

Comment: When you issue a `dir node_modules`, do you see something like `01/12/2016  09:21 PM    <JUNCTION>     my-module [C:\Users\Nizar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\my-module]`? If not, then something went wrong with the linkage

Comment: oh yes! 01/15/2016  11:02 AM    <JUNCTION>     my-module [C:\Users\Nizar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\my-module]

Comment: its weird, i can still access it using cd. ideas?

Comment: if you `cd node_modules\my-module`, you end up in your module folder, right? With an `index.js` or something else as specified by the `main` key in your package.json?

Comment: yes, index.js is not the file i use for my-module tho!

Comment: it worked when i changed index.js !! thanks, feel free to write an answer so i can mark it with V :)

Comment: `npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, symlink 'C:\Users\...\' -> 'C:\Users\...\'`  can you pls help @NizarBlond I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few things to try. On Windows, `npm link` is handled by creating junction points. Issuing a `dir node_modules` command should result in a line like:

```
01/15/2016 11:02 AM <JUNCTION> my-module [C:\Users\Nizar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\my-module]
```

Assuming that's there, then the problem is more than likely:

1. A lack of an `index.js` file (which is the default filename node uses to resolve modules)
2. You're using a different file than `index.js` as the main file of your module, in which case you need to tell node what that file is, by using the `main` key in your `package.json` file.

For example (taken from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heroku/node-js-sample/master/package.json)):

```
{
  "name": "node-js-sample",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "A sample Node.js app using Express 4",
  "main": "index.js", // <-- LIKE THIS
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "author": "Mark Pundsack",
  "contributors": [
    "Zeke Sikelianos <zeke@sikelianos.com> (http://zeke.sikelianos.com)"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```